# How can I add a contact to DOM and array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, builder-pattern

Hello dear developers,

I have this code in builder pattern and I want to make a phone book ,

I want , when an user clicks on add button a contact would be added to DOM and push to records,

I need the name and number would be given from user and I wrote such a thing but I have probelm with

their scops and also adding to dom with this pattern
I wrote this `phoneBook.addRecords(addContactName.value , addContactPhone.value);`
but it has an error due to its scope,
I want those value to make an object with `PhoneBookRecord(name, phone)` constructor and push them to `records` array
also I want them to be happend after `addContactButton` is clicked also after pushing them , I want them to be added in dom with `builder`.

thank you all to help me in advanced.

```
function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.text = function (text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    //others add here
    this.setClass = function (className) {
        this.element.className = className;
        return this;
    };

    this.setType = function (type) {
        this.element.type = type;
        return this;
    }


    this.appendTo = function (container) {
        container.append(this.element);
        return this;
    }



    this.build = function () {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function (name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    },
};

function PhoneBookRecord(name, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;

}

function PhoneBook() {
    this.records = [];

    this.addRecords = function(name, number) {
        let record = new PhoneBookRecord(name, number);
        this.records.push(record);
        
    }
    //add search remove functions add here
    
}

function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

    this.init = function () {

        const h1 = builder
            .create("h1")
            .text("Phonebook App")
            .setClass("title")
            .appendTo(this.container);
        //other elements add here

        const search = builder
            .create("input")
            .setClass("search")
            .setType("text")
            .appendTo(this.container);

        const addContactText = builder
            .create("p")
            .text("Add New Contact")
            .setClass("addContactText")
            .appendTo(this.container);

        const addContactName = builder
            .create("input")
            .setClass("addContactName")
            .setType("text")
            .appendTo(this.container);

        const addContactPhone = builder
            .create("input")
            .setClass("addContactPhone")
            .setType("number")
            .appendTo(this.container);

        const addContactButton = builder
            .create("button")
            .setClass("addContactButton")
            .text("Add")
            .appendTo(this.container);

        const hr = builder
            .create("hr")
            .appendTo(this.container);
        
        phoneBook.addRecords(addContactName.value , addContactPhone.value);
        console.log(phoneBook.records);
        
        
    };

    //other functions 
   document.onclick = function(e) {
       if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains("addContactButton")){
           phoneBook.addRecords(this.addContactName , this.addContactPhone);
       }
   }

}

const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

Comment: What is the specific problem and where are you stuck?

Comment: I mean when an user clicks on add a contact would be made by the name and number input value and be added to DOM also be pushed to array ./ I did it but that handler is out of scope

Comment: That's a start but still not very clear. What handler...which scope. [edit] the question to make it clear and make reference to specific methods. See [mcve]

Comment: I have edited , I wish it would be clear